# Is it possible to append data to an xls file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, xls

I am trying to add a large dataset to an existing xls spreadsheet.
I'm currently writing to it using a pandas dataframe and the `.to_excel()` function, however this erases the existing data in the (multi-sheet) workbook. The existing spreadsheet is very large and complex,it also interacts with several other files, so I can't convert it to xlsx or read and rewrite all of the data, as I've seen some suggestions on other questions. I want the data that I am adding to be pasted starting from a set row in an existing sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use the library xlsxwriter , link= https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io
code example :

```
import xlsxwriter
Name="MyFile"+".xlsx"
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(Name)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write("A1", "Incident category".decode("utf-8"))
worksheet.write("B1", "Longitude".decode("utf-8"))
worksheet.write("C1", "Latitude".decode("utf-8"))
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Does this work for xls files too? I had a working solution for xlsx, but not for xls

Comment: i think its compatible .just try to rename it , Name="MyFile"+".xlsx" to Name="MyFile"+".xls"

Comment: The docs open with 'Xlsxwriter is a Python module that can write text... in an Excel 2007+ XLSX file.' Xls files do not fit that description

Comment: @alphatheta7 to read / write in xls files use xlwt librarry.